# Openshift add multiple contributors to project

Tags: git, openshift

I'm working on a project, but I need other members of the team to have access to the git repo on openshift. I tried to add their public RSA key to the set of recognized keys using the web interface, but all of them still get following error when trying to git clone the repo:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm doing something wrong, because all the ssh keys related solutions I found seem to work for most people, but me. Is it possible to grant access to contributors, who do not have an openshift account anyway?
thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `rhc member-add` command to give access to your OpenShift domain.rhc is a command-line tool that you can use to work with OpenShift. It is a ruby gem that you can install by typing `gem install rhc`. To give user1 and user2 edit access to your domain, execute the following command

```
$ rhc member-add user1 user2 -n <mydomain> -r edit
```

Comment: thank you for response, I do know rhc tool, but if I understand correctly,what you suggest would only work for users, who already have an OpenShift account, I suppose. But I need to grant access to teammates, who do not have one, but could still git clone and push to the repo